# Convert int to bitmask/flags when deserializing json wtih RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I am getting REST requests that include a 32 bit integer. I'd like to convert this to a set of flags based on the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum TowerStatus
{
    NotUsed = 4194304,
    DireAncientTop = 2097152,
    DireAncientBottom = 1048576,
    DireBottomTier3 = 524288,
    DireBottomTier2 = 262144,
    DireBottomTier1 = 131072,
    DireMiddleTier3 = 65536,
    DireMiddleTier2 = 32768,
    DireMiddleTier1 = 16384,
    DireTopTier3 = 8192,
    DireTopTier2 = 4096,
    DireTopTier1 = 2048,
    RadiantAncientTop = 1024,
    RadiantAncientBottom = 512,
    RadiantBottomTier3 = 256,
    RadiantBottomTier2 = 128,
    RadiantBottomTier1 = 64,
    RadiantMiddleTier3 = 32,
    RadiantMiddleTier2 = 16,
    RadiantMiddleTier1 = 8,
    RadiantTopTier3 = 4,
    RadiantTopTier2 = 2,
    RadiantTopTier1 = 1
}
```

But i am unsure how to even try and deserialize the int into a CLR object.

I'm using the default JSON deserializer provided by RestSharp but even implementing a custom deserializer, I wouldn't know how to just deserialize one value in a different manner to everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you would use RestSharp for deserializing the request on the server, JSON.NET usually handles this pretty well.

So for example if you have the following class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public TowerStatus Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and the following JSON input:

```
string json = "{\"Foo\": 393216 }";
```

you could deserialize it back to the model and the enum flags will be respected:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(response);
Console.WriteLine(model.Foo);
// prints DireBottomTier1, DireBottomTier2
```

If for some reason you need to use RestSharp for deserializing, then you could write a custom deserializer:

```
public class RestSharpJsonNetDeserializer : IDeserializer
{
    public RestSharpJsonNetDeserializer()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json";
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

that could be used like this:

```
string json = "{\"Foo\": 393216 }";
var response = new RestResponse();
response.Content = json;
var deserializer = new RestSharpJsonNetDeserializer();
var model = deserializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(response);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that JSON.Net would deserialize the int to Enum flags with no changes?

Comment: I switched to using Json.NET and that solved all of my problems.